# Items in ListView with different background color

Tags: android, listview

I know this question was asked several times but none of the answer allowed me to find a solution. Here is my problem : I created a ListView with around 50 items. Few of them needs to have a white background while the other have a yellow one. To do this, I created two layouts feed1.xml and feed2.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ReadUnread"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/FeedItem"
        android:src="@drawable/readunread"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
    >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/FeedItem"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:textSize="12sp" 
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:background="@color/yellow">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The second one is exactly the same except the background color I replaced to "@color/white".

The source code which create the ListView is like this (It's a light version of course) :

```
public class ItemsListActivity extends ListActivity implements Runnable {

    static final int FEED_RESULT = 0;
    private ArrayList<Feed> feeds;
    private FeedAdapter m_feedAdapter;
    public ListView lv;

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            createListAdapter();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void createListAdapter()
    {
        m_feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(this, R.layout.feed, feeds);
        setListAdapter(m_feedAdapter);

        lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(0);
        lv.setDividerHeight(2);
        lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ItemsListActivity.this,
                            ReaderActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("id", feeds.get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(intent, FEED_RESULT);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    private Boolean getFeeds() {
        feeds = new ArrayList<Feed>();
    }

    private class FeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Feed> {

        private ArrayList<Feed> feeds;

        public FeedAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Feed> feeds) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, feeds);
            this.feeds = feeds;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            Feed f = feeds.get(position);
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                if (f.getWhite() == 0)
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.feed1, null);
                else
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.feed2, null);
            }
            if (f != null) {
                TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.FeedItem);
                ImageView im = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ReadUnread);
                if (tt != null) {
                    tt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+f.getSubject()+"</b>"+"<small> >>"+f.getAuthor()+"</small>"));
                    tt.setTag(f.getId());
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my application (on the emulator or on a device), it seems to be great until I scroll. When I scroll the list, few yellow items become white then when I scroll again, they become yellow again. It's exactly the same with white items. It seems to be completely random... The background colors are swapped and swapped again... I tried a lot of things (like setCacheColorHint() or setScrollingCacheEnabled()) but nothing seems to work. Do you have any idea?

Thx for your help.

**Solution**

Ok, Problem solved!

Two important things to modify :

1. Because of the recycling, It's clearly not a good idea to create two layouts. The best solution is to create only one layout and to set the background color in the getView() function.
2. By doing this, it's necessary to set the background color for **all the cases**! Even if the default background color is set ("yellow" in my case).

So the right implementation of my getView() function become :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        Feed f = feeds.get(position);
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.feed1, null);
        }
        if (f != null) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.FeedItem);
            ImageView im = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ReadUnread);
            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+f.getSubject()+"</b>"+"<small> >>"+f.getAuthor()+"</small>"));
                tt.setTag(f.getId());
                if (f.getWhite == 0) {
                      im.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                      tt.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                }
                else {
                      im.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
                      tt.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of creating 2 layouts, just create one and just programatically assign colors in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

set android:cacheColorHint property to trasparent color:

android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

for Reference see link:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html

Comment: In the "createListAdapter" function, I already did "lv.setCacheColorHint(0);" but it didn't change anything...